# Convert single column to single row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

I have a table with a single column like so:

```
+-------------+
|(Column Name)|
+-------------+
|Data1        |
+-------------+
|Data2        |
+-------------+
|Data3        |
+-------------+
|Data4        |
+-------------+
|Data5        |
+-------------+
```

What I want to do seems very simple, but I am not able to find any examples of it anywhere. All I want is to convert the above column into a single row like so:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| (Col1)| (Col2)| (Col3)| (Col4)| (Col5)|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Data1 | Data2 | Data3 | Data4 | Data5 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I'm sure this is a very simple task, but I am extremely new to working with databases. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Pivot will help you

Comment: Google : Dynamic Pivot in Sql Server

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do pivot as below:

```
Select * from (
    Select colname, RowN = Row_Number() over (order by colname) from #cols
    ) a
    pivot (max(colname) for RowN in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) p
```

For dynamic list of columns

```
Declare @cols nvarchar(max)
Declare @query nvarchar(max)

Select @cols = stuff((select ','+QuoteName(Row_Number() over (Order by (Select NULL))) from #cols for xml path('')),1,1,'')
Select @query = ' Select * from (
    Select colname, RowN = Row_Number() over (order by colname) from #cols
    ) a
    pivot (max(colname) for RowN in (' + @cols + ')) p '

Exec sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: @Kennan Thank you! Works great!

Comment: The second option for dynamic list of columns was really helpful for me. Thank you Kannan Kandasamy

Can I use CONCAT() to get a single column with concatenated strings from all the columns?

Answer (score 1):

**Pivot Query:**

```
CREATE TABLE Sales ([Month] VARCHAR(20) ,SaleAmount INT)

INSERT INTO Sales VALUES ('January', 100)
INSERT INTO Sales VALUES ('February', 200)
INSERT INTO Sales VALUES ('March', 300)

SELECT * FROM SALES
```

**Example:**

```
SELECT  [January]
      , [February]
      , [March]
FROM    ( SELECT    [Month]
                  , SaleAmount
          FROM      Sales
        ) p PIVOT ( SUM(SaleAmount)
                    FOR [Month] 
                      IN ([January],[February],[March])
                  ) AS pvt
```