# How to convert a single column to a single row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I couldn't find a good solution for my question, I have a table for a CheckBoxList like this:

```
  ID  |  CheckBoxList
-----------------------
   1  |       0
   2  |       1
   3  |       2
   4  |       0
```

I want to use it in an application for reporting (named StimulSoft), What I need is the way to convert column to row, something like this:

```
CheckBox0  |  CheckBox1  | CheckBox2  | CheckBox3
----------------------------------------------------
     0     |      1      |      2     |     0
```

How can I acheive that? I read some stuffs about pivot and unpivot but I couldn't make it work. I even tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45169930/4344976), it could help me a little bit but when I tried to change column `[0]` or `[1]` to `[ch1]` or `[ch2]` I encountered to an error saying `Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then CheckBoxList end) as checkbox_0,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then CheckBoxList end) as checkbox_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then CheckBoxList end) as checkbox_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then CheckBoxList end) as checkbox_3       
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Note that this will return four columns regardless of the number in the table.  If you need as many columns as rows . . . then you need dynamic SQL.  I might caution you against then and to use string aggregation instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to transform column data into row data. Using 'PIVOT' function

```
select CheckBox0, CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3
from
(
  select Id, CheckBoxList
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(Id)
  for CheckBoxList in (CheckBox0, CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3)
) piv;
```